# Viewing file while recording livestreams

Tags: streaming, video-streaming, recording

I'm currently recording a livestream via VLC player. Will it interrupt the recording session in anyway, if while it's recording, I play the dumped video file?

Answer (score 1):

Any other process can access the file and as long as it doesn't try to write to it, it will not interfere.

Note though that a player trying to open a file that's currently been written to might complain about it being damaged or incomplete. Under no circumstances should you allow a player to "repair" the file that's currently being written to. It may also reduce functionality, like e.g. not allow you to fast forward/backward.